# How to manage state in web server farm which is not user related information

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, architecture, asp.net-core-webapi, server-farm

I am currently working on a .NET Core REST styled API that is written in Microservices and we were not maintaining any state but then we had this requirement of keeping a track of logged in users.

fortunately, we are using SignalR for real-time data updation for every logged in user and that seems like the most accurate option to maintain the state of the logged-in users by having some static Data Structure in memory and maintaining the list of logged-in users but *statics do not work well in web server farms, also we will lose our state on any server refresh*

That said, now I have to save the state that is not user-related and I want to do it efficiently and I don't think SQL Server will be a good option to maintain the state so I'm not really sure where to go from here.

What do you think the best option for non-user-related state management in this particular scenario?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Your question is too broad. In general, you have `IDistributedCache`. It can be backed by SQL Server or Redis out of the box, but you can add your own providers.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Thanks for pointing out, I just edited my question and I'm just looking for a good option for state management. I will have a look at IDistributedCache